# Angular binding expression VS binding method

Tags: angular

What is the difference, if any, between binding to a component method and binding to an expression that executes code?

As in, does angular have a way of tracking properties, such as observables or pub/sub, that can't be applied to methods? Is there a way to see that code or test it?

expression: `<p>{{firstValue + secondValue}}</p>`

method: `<p>{{sumValues(firstValue, secondValue)}}</p>`

For context I'm trying to check if the expression gets executed on every change (`doCheck` hook). I know binding to a method does but not sure how test how many times the expression is executed.

Couple of articles explaining why this happens:

[Why you should never use function calls in Angular template expressions](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)

[When not to use methods in templates](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking here. The linked articles explain it pretty well no? Do you have a specific question? If this is your question" "I know binding to a method does but not sure how test how many times the expression is executed." - simply put a console call inside your sumValue method and you can see?

Comment: @MikeOne I want to know if using the "expression" example is different from the "method" example under the hood. i.e. does it get called every time `doCheck` runs or only when the `firstValue` and `secondValue` variables change? If it is different then why is that? How does angular know not to check those variables? Does that make it any clearer?
Sure the method example is pretty easy to test with a log but how would I achieve the same for expression?

Comment: Right, So for the expression - these are values inside the component scope so angular 'knows' when these values change simply by diffing those values (bit more complicated then that but still) every change detection cycle. So if they change, Angular knows to update the DOM (which is the expensive operation). For the method however, Angular does not assume it is a pure function. So Angular needs to call the method every cycle in order to find out if the result from the function has changed.

Comment: This is potentially an expensive operation, depending on what you function does. The example (simply summing values) shouldn't be problematic. But if for example you have subscriptions in there or async stuff in general or heavy calculations, it starts to become a problem. So the basic rule is - do not use method calls from the template.

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne. I guess I'm looking for a more technical explanation of what angular does in the background. I.e does it use observables or some sort of pub sub to track variables and mark them as changed? Not that I don't believe it would be good to understand the implementation and why it behaves that way. Also strange those two articles don't mention it as a workaround for simple methods